# Is it possible for an electron in the atom to spontaneously change the direction of its spin component on the z-axis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, atoms

By "spontaneously" I mean without interacting with any external field.
 
More specifically, can the $S_z$ component of an electron's spin collapse into one of its two possible states ($S_{z\pm} = \pm\frac{\hbar}{2}$) *spontaneously* within the atom?
 
 
I suppose that normally the state of $S_z$ for an electron in the atom is a linear combination of its two possible states, e.g. $S_z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} S_{z+} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} S_{z-}. $ 
Can $S_z$ collapse into one state and then back to the superposition state, then collapse again etc., without any external *interference*? 
If so, what would be the conditions for this to happen? Could it be related to spin-orbit coupling or other phenomena inside the atom?

Comment: It can be in _any_ linear combination, not just this one.

Comment: Do you mean that the coefficients of the linear combination could be any (as long as the sum of their squares equals 1), since the probability for either state is not necessarily 1/2? In any case, this means that prior to measurement and therefore interaction, the spin of the electron in the atom is in a state given by superposition of $\pm1/2\hbar$, right? This is part of what I was asking.

Comment: To be clearer, in general the superposed spin state of the electron (even _**within the atom**_) would be something like: $\lvert \psi\rangle = a \; \lvert S_{z+}\rangle + b \; \lvert S_{z-}\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

We are in the quantum mechanical regime when talking of electrons and atoms. This means the electrons are in bound states, i.e. with fixed energy levels, and cannot "jump" levels because of energy consrvation. Generally to be found with a different spin orientation would require energy input or output, i.e. an interaction:

Look at the [fine structure](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydfin.html) of the hydrogen atom.:

> When the familiar red spectral line of the hydrogen spectrum is examined at very high resolution, it is found to be a closely-spaced doublet. This splitting is called fine structure and was one of the first experimental evidences for electron spin.

[image: finestrH]

> The small splitting of the spectral line is attributed to an interaction between the electron spin S and the orbital angular momentum L. It is called the spin-orbit interaction.

So there can be no "collapse" as you envisage it. After all "collapse" is another vocabulary for "measurement", which means "interaction".

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly, this means that, since the splitting of the spectral line is always observed, the electron in the atom is always in a linear combination of the two spin states, correct?
Does this imply that it's not possible for the electron's spin to be in one of the two states without any external interaction? (I mentioned spin-orbit coupling only as a possible factor, just for the sake of example.)

Comment: No, it means that if energy is provided to expel the electron from where it was, it is seen that there are two states it could be, because two different energy photons have to be provided. It was either in one energy level, or the other with the opposite spin. either or, no other choice. No super[position . energy is always conserved. In emission spectra, the doublet appears because the electron at the red frequency, is either in one spin state or the other, cannot be in both.

Comment: Ok, so essentially: since the electron in the atom is always in either one or the other spin state, it means that it cannot change state on its own without any external energy provision. So it cannot "fluctuate" between the two states, correct? It's just to ensure that I understand, thanks.

Comment: Yes, energy levels cannot arbitrarily change

Answer (score 0):

Without any external field and in the absence of orbital momentum the spin states are degenerate. The system is then in a mixed state described by a diagonal density matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}~.$$